# Insert method not comparing properly

Tags: c++, string, iterator, linked-list, binary-search-tree

I have this insert method that is supposed to be inserting nodes into a BST that contains names and ages of people. The tree itself is sorted by age with each node containing a linked list of people that are of that age.

My insert method for this tree is not comparing these nodes to each other properly. With input like

```
insert 1 50 john
insert 1 30 elvis
insert 1 90 david
insert 1 50 james
insert 1 95 abel
insert 1 80 esther
insert 1 95 vivian
insert 1 95 barbara
insert 1 50 james
```

I should only see the insert fail once with the duplicate insertion of James. Instead my code seems to make two age 50 nodes and fail at inserting vivian

```
Input Command: insert 1 50 john
Input Command: insert 1 30 elvis
Input Command: insert 1 90 david
Input Command: insert 1 50 james
Input Command: insert 1 95 abel
Input Command: insert 1 80 esther
Input Command: insert 1 95 vivian
    --- Failed.
Input Command: insert 1 95 barbara
        --- Failed.
Input Command: insert 1 50 james
```

I am unsure why this is happening. It does not even seem to be performing comparisons at the right times either.

Either way here is my code

```
    bool insert(const int &a, const string &n) {
        BinaryNode* t = new BinaryNode;
        BinaryNode* parent;
        t->it = t->nameList.begin();
        t->nameList.insert(t->it ,n);
        t->age = a;
        t->left = NULL;
        t->right = NULL;
        parent = NULL;

        if(isEmpty()){ 
            root = t;
            return true;
        }
        else {
            BinaryNode* curr;
            curr = root;
            while(curr) {
                parent = curr;
                if(t->age > curr->age) 
                    curr = curr->right;
                else 
                    curr = curr->left;
            }

            if(t->age == parent->age) {
                for(list<string>::iterator ti = parent->nameList.begin(); ti != parent->nameList.end(); ti++) {
                    string temp = *ti;
                    cout << temp << endl;
                    if(n.compare(temp)) 
                        return false;
                    else if(ti == parent->nameList.end())
                        parent->nameList.insert(ti,n);
                }
                return true;
            }

            if(t->age < parent->age) {
                parent->left = t;
                return true;
            }
            else {
                parent->right = t;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you assumed that in a BST, if a duplicate value is inserted, it will surely be a child of the original value, which is incorrect. For example, consider this case.

```
    50
   /  \
  40   60
   \
    50
```

So, what you'd like to do is keep checking the duplicate age as you traverse down the tree instead of doing `if(t->age == parent->age)`. You can update your while loop as follows-

```
while(curr){
    parent = curr;
    if(t->age == curr->age){
        //Check for duplicate name here
    }
    else if(t->age > cur->age)
        curr = curr->right;
    else
        curr = curr->left;
}
```

Also, you should free up the memory of the new node `t` on condition of fail.

Answer (score 0):

I think this

```
if(n.compare(temp)) 
  return false;
else if(ti == parent->nameList.end())
  parent->nameList.insert(ti,n);
```

should be

```
if(!n.compare(temp)) 
  return false;
else if(ti == parent->nameList.end())
  parent->nameList.insert(ti,n);
```

by writing `if (n.compare(temp))` every time the same age is detected it fails when the name differs.